# How to pass data from Java Activity to react native?

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-bridge

I am unable to pass data from java activity to react native.
I am processing a card payment, and when the payment is done, the response is stored in a variable called message. I need to pass this message to my react native code.

// Java module, the data I want to pass is in "message"

public class HelloWorldModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener{
    Activity activity;

ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    public HelloWorldModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext,Activity activity) {
        super(reactContext); //required by React Native
        this.reactContext= reactContext;
          this.activity= activity;
           reactContext.addActivityEventListener(this); //Register this native module as Activity result listener

```
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // ReactApplicationContext reactContext = this.getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactApplicationContext();
    // reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit();
    // reactContext
    // .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
    // .emit('message', message);

/*
 *  We advise you to do a further verification of transaction's details on your server to be
 *  sure everything checks out before providing service or goods.
*/
if (requestCode == RaveConstants.RAVE_REQUEST_CODE && data != null) {
    String message = data.getStringExtra("response");
    // Log.e("RAVE",message);
    if (resultCode == RavePayActivity.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "SUCCESS " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (resultCode == RavePayActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "ERROR " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (resultCode == RavePayActivity.RESULT_CANCELLED) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "CANCELLED " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
// else {
//      super.onActivityResult(activity, requestCode, resultCode, data);
// }
```

}

//  @Override
//   public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//       Toast.makeText( activity , "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//   }

```
@Override
```

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

}

```
@Override
//getName is required to define the name of the module represented in JavaScript
public String getName() { 
    return "HelloWorld";
}

@ReactMethod
public void sayHi(Callback errorCallback, Callback successCallback) {
    try{
        int amount = 30;//call.argument("amount");
                    String narration = "Payment for soup";//call.argument("nara");
                    String countryCode = "NG"; //call.argument("countryCode");
                    String currency =  "NGN"; //call.argument("currency");
                    String amountText = "50";//call.argument("amountText");
                    String email = "*****@yahoo.com";//call.argument("email");
                    String name = "Ubanna Danny";//call.argument("name");
                    String paymentId = "a98sjkhdjdu";//call.argument("paymentId");



                    String key ="FLWPUBK-****-X";
                     String encryptionKey = "****";

                            new RavePayManager(activity).setAmount(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(amount)))
                            .setCountry(countryCode)
                            .setCurrency(currency)
                            .setEmail(email)
                            .setfName(name)
                            .setlName("")
                            .setNarration(narration)
                            .setPublicKey(key)
                            .setEncryptionKey(encryptionKey)
                            .setTxRef(paymentId)
                            .acceptMpesaPayments(false)
                            .acceptAccountPayments(true)
                            .acceptCardPayments(true)
                            .acceptGHMobileMoneyPayments(false)
                            .onStagingEnv(false)
                            .allowSaveCardFeature(true)
                            .initialize();
    } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
        errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }                  
}
```

}

// React native code

```
   // async function to call the Java native method
    async sayHiFromJava() {
      HelloWorld.sayHi( (err) => {console.log(err)}, (msg) => {console.log(msg)} );
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

use device emitter to send data from native to react native

in on activity result add following code

```
ReactContext context = this.getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();

context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit();
context
  .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
  .emit('message', message);
```

in react native add Dives emiter listener

```
import {DeviceEventEmitter} from 'react-native';

EmitterModule.addListener('message', (message) => {
  console.log(message);
};
```

Comment: Please clarify what line exactly I should put the code im getting this error, when i build - error: unclosed character literal
        .emit('message', message);

Comment: Do I need to include this - WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
params.putString("eventProperty", "someValue");

Comment: i have eddited my code if u are getting error for emit() use above code

Comment: @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ReactApplicationContext reactContext = this.getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactApplicationContext();
        reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit();
        reactContext
        .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
        .emit('message', message);

Comment: please im error this error -- error: unclosed character literal
        .emit('message', message);

Comment: use ```this.getReactApplicationContext().getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("message", message)```